# How to add buttons to the group box, and sets button.Text = item from table in SQL in run time mode

Tags: c#, winforms

How to add buttons to the GroupBox, and sets `button.Text = item` from table in SQL in run time mode by C#?

Comment: Take some globals which define x y offsets, x y space between buttons, x y size of button and maximal buttons per row, actual row,actual column. Then iterate over sql table,create the buttons using the given global vars to set the location of each button. Then apply text. Then add the buttons to the parents .Controls collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `GroupBox.Controlls.Add()` method to add new controls to it. Since you have to properly align them, I would first add a `FlowLayoutPanel` to the `GroupBox` (with `Docking.Fill`), which will float your `Buttons` (you can define vertical or horizontal flow and if the buttons should be wrapped or not when the width is reached). If you use a `FlowLayoutPanel`, you would add the buttons to the `FlowLayoutPanel` (using `FlowLayoutPanel.Controlls.Add()` and not directly to the `GroupBox`).

You can create a new Button as you would create a new object from any class (i.e. `var btn = new Button()`). The button text can be set to any string, so either your item is of type string or you need to use `button.Text = item.Name` (or any other representable string value in your item). You can specify the tag property of the button (e.g. `button.Tag = item`) to have a reference to the item behind the button. Finally, you can add an event handler to the button to capture when it is clicked by the user.